# C: Different address in a struct?

Tags: c, data-structures, memory-address, 8051

I'm using IAR-8051. Is it possible to have some variables with different absolute address in a struct?

Example:

```
__sfr struct
{
    unsigned char DATA    @ 0x80;
    unsigned char MODE1   @ 0xB1;
    unsigned char MODE2   @ 0xB2
} GPIO0;
```

This is my desire:

```
GPIO0.DATA = 0x12;
GPIO0.MODE1 = 0xF0;
```

Comment: No.

In C a struct is always continuous, but what you do, is could create a struct with padding and declare a pointer to it at a fixed address.

Comment: Are trying to access memory mapped peripherals or something? There is a known pattern for that.

Comment: But don't apply the anti-pattern of using identifers starting with `_`, it means taking risks without a benefit.

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm writing a header file for special-function-registers for 8051, but it's registers were placed very messy (a little of arm coxter-m3 is too). I know the solution in the compiler. It seems no one noticed, somethings like that: extend_struct {};

Comment: If you know a solution but do not want to use it, then please explain in the question why not. Provide enough details on that rejected solution to allow understanding your reasons for rejecting it.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.